# Mathematica - Functions with Lists

Tags: list, function, wolfram-mathematica

I got this error in *Mathematica* today:

```
Set::shape: "Lists {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0} and {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,{1}} are not the same shape" >>
```

And after 3 of those :

```
General::stop : Further output of Set::shape will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
```

I am confused as to why I cannot append a "1" to my list of zeros. Is this because I cannot edit the list that is passed into the function? If so, how could I edit that list and somehow return or print it?

Here is my full code:

```
notFunctioningFunction[list_] := (For[i = 1, i < 10, i++, list = Append[list, {1}]]; 
  Print[list])
list = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
notFunctioningFunction[list]
```

The reason why I am appending a "{1}" is because in my function, I am solving an equation, and getting the value of the variable which outputs {1}. Here is my code for that :

```
varName / . Solve[ function1 == function2 ]
```

Obviously I am a beginner with *Mathematica* so please be patient :)

Thanks,

Bucco

Comment: At the risk of stating the bleedin' obvious, `{1}!=1`.  Also -- step away from the `For` statement newcomer, you're not in `C` world any more; just walk away nice and easy over towards the functional operations over there.  `Append` and `Join` are two of your options, as @Xerxes' answer suggests.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have removed my for loop and I am using a Table instead. (it seems to work now :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dear Mathematica beginner.

First, when you use something like

```
{a,b} = {c,d,e};
```

in Mathematica, between two lists, the program has a difficulty because this is a construct used to assign values to variables, and it requires (among other things) the two lists to be equal.

If what you want is just to add a "1" to an existing and named list, one at a time, the best construct is:

```
AppendTo[list, 1];
```

*(this construct will modify the variable 'list')*

or

```
list = Join[list, {1}];
```

Second: about the error messages, they are printed 3 times by default in an evaluation, then muted so that a long list of identical error messages does not clutter your display.

Third, if what you need is adding 10 1s to a list, there is no need to construct that in a loop. You can do that in one pass:

```
list = Join[list, Table[1, {10}]]
```

or, more cryptic for beginners

```
list = Join[list, Array[1&, 10]]
```

Comment: Or, even shorter but perhaps more to the point `ConstantArray[1,10]`.

Comment: Thanks so much, I decided to use the table approach.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark : thanks, you're right. And this function is available since version 6.

Answer (score 3):

Append needs to take one list and one element. Like so:

```
 Append[{1,2,3,4},5]
```

If you have two lists, you can use Join. Like so:

```
 Join[{1,2,3,4},{5}]
```

Both of these will yield the same result: {1,2,3,4,5}.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I decided to use the table approach though.